# Using Custom Claims in React Firebase Hooks to access specific database Ref

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, react-hooks

I'm pretty new to React Hooks and I'm trying to figure out how to use react-firebase-hooks with custom claims.

My firebase Realtime Database is structured like so :

groups 
--- key1
------- clients
------- info
--- key2
------- clients
------- info

Each user has a custom claim named "group" carrying the group Key.

I have this code so far but it's throwing me a:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasCancelCallback' of undefined
> at ChildEventRegistration.createCancelEvent"

```
function ClientList() {
  const [firebaseUser, loadingFirebaseUser] = useAuthState(auth);
  const [userGroup, setUserGroup] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchClaims = async () => {
      const {
        claims: { group },
      } = await firebaseUser.getIdTokenResult();
      setUserGroup(group);
    };

    if (firebaseUser) fetchClaims();
  }, [firebase.database(), firebaseUser]);

  const [snapshots, loading, error] = useList(
    firebase.database().ref(`groups/${userGroup}/clients`)
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>List of Clients</h2>
      {userGroup && <p>{userGroup}</p>}
      {error && <strong>Error: {error}</strong>}
      {loading && <span>List: Loading...</span>}
      {!loading && snapshots && (
        <ul>
          {snapshots.map((v) => (
            <li key={v.key}>
              {v.key}}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I might be missing something very obvious here.

Here's a full stack trace of the error :

```
overrideMethod @ react_devtools_backend.js:2557
printWarnings @ vendors~main.chunk.js:36207
handleWarnings @ vendors~main.chunk.js:36212
push../node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js.connection.onmessage @ vendors~main.chunk.js:36277
vendors~main.chunk.js:28144 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasCancelCallback' of undefined
    at ChildEventRegistration.createCancelEvent (vendors~main.chunk.js:28144)
    at vendors~main.chunk.js:23797
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at viewRemoveEventRegistration (vendors~main.chunk.js:23796)
    at syncPointRemoveEventRegistration (vendors~main.chunk.js:24047)
    at syncTreeRemoveEventRegistration (vendors~main.chunk.js:24417)
    at onComplete (vendors~main.chunk.js:24743)
    at Object.onComplete (vendors~main.chunk.js:25874)
    at vendors~main.chunk.js:16786
    at PersistentConnection.onDataMessage_ (vendors~main.chunk.js:17069)
    at Connection.onDataMessage_ (vendors~main.chunk.js:15624)
    at Connection.onPrimaryMessageReceived_ (vendors~main.chunk.js:15617)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (vendors~main.chunk.js:15497)
    at WebSocketConnection.appendFrame_ (vendors~main.chunk.js:15050)
    at WebSocketConnection.handleIncomingFrame (vendors~main.chunk.js:15108)
    at WebSocket.mySock.onmessage (vendors~main.chunk.js:14984)
ChildEventRegistration.createCancelEvent @ vendors~main.chunk.js:28144
(anonymous) @ vendors~main.chunk.js:23797
viewRemoveEventRegistration @ vendors~main.chunk.js:23796
syncPointRemoveEventRegistration @ vendors~main.chunk.js:24047
syncTreeRemoveEventRegistration @ vendors~main.chunk.js:24417
onComplete @ vendors~main.chunk.js:24743
(anonymous) @ vendors~main.chunk.js:25874
(anonymous) @ vendors~main.chunk.js:16786
PersistentConnection.onDataMessage_ @ vendors~main.chunk.js:17069
Connection.onDataMessage_ @ vendors~main.chunk.js:15624
Connection.onPrimaryMessageReceived_ @ vendors~main.chunk.js:15617
(anonymous) @ vendors~main.chunk.js:15497
WebSocketConnection.appendFrame_ @ vendors~main.chunk.js:15050
WebSocketConnection.handleIncomingFrame @ vendors~main.chunk.js:15108
mySock.onmessage @ vendors~main.chunk.js:14984
```

Comment: I don't immediately see what causes this error in the code you shared. Can you edit your question to show exactly where the error is coming from, for example by sharing an entire stack trace and showing how that relates to your code?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen it seems like the error is coming from the fact that I'm using the "useList" hook with a variable, and I don't really know how to wait for the group state to be defined before actually getting a snapshot. I've edited the question to add a full stack trace of the error !

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Unfortunately I have no experience with the `useList` hook. But can't you move the `useList` right after/before the `setUserGroup(group)` call?

Comment: Trying to do that after the `setUserGroup(group)` gives me this error :
`React Hook "useList" is called in function "fetchClaims" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter`

I might try to do a custom hook then...